# Notepad++ - file bookmarks working like web page bookmarks in web browser?

Tags: notepad++, bookmarks

There are line bookmarks in Notepad++ but I have a large number of files (100+) I need to visit from time to time, just like web pages. I can't have all of them open as this would create too many tabs. Is there an option or plugin that allows me to keep the list of "frequently visited files" in N++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Notepad++ session management](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/session-management)

> Sessions are a set of files opened in Notepad++. They store the open
>   files, the active file (and which view, see the section about
>   Multi-View), the current selection and position in the file, the
>   current bookmarks (see Bookmarks) and the current language (see the
>   section about Languages). Using sessions, you can open a set of
>   (related) files with one action.

Comment: the link is dead. I'll post back here if I find a live one.

Comment: could be this one: http://mfoster.com/npp/SessionMgr.html

Answer (score 4):

A workaround. You can have a **file called `links.txt`**. Place full path to each favorite file as a separate line. After selecting a line press Alt-F5 (Run / Open file) to open it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is too late, but I found an answer, and decided to share it:

[Explorer plugin for Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/) by Jens Lorenz has Favorites functionality.

Answer (score 2):

There exists "Notepad++ Favorites" plugin - https://github.com/heldersepu/nppfavorites

put the NppFavorites.dll into installation folder to manually install.

Answer (score 0):

I use the customizable "Run" menu of Notepad++ as a sort of bookmark location.

You add items to the Run menu by editing the `shortcuts.xml` file inside the `<UserDefinedCommands>` tags. For example, to add that file itself as a bookmark, you would have:

```
<UserDefinedCommands>
    <Command name="Modify shortcuts.xml file" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe C:\Users\<NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml</Command>
</UserDefinedCommands>
```

This way you can add any file as bookmark. You only need to prefix it with `$(NPP_DIRECTORY)\notepad++.exe`  (or equivalently `$(NPP_FULL_FILE_PATH)`) if the file format has a different default application to open it than Notepad++. Otherwise, just write `...Key="0">C:\Users\<NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml</Command>`. If the file path includes spaces, you need to wrap it in quotes.

As you can guess, this means that you can add other programs as bookmarks as well. E.g. I have a bookmark to edit the config file of a program on Notepad++; right below that, I have an entry for an executable to force the config changes to that program to take effect. The latter (executing other programs) is presumably the intended purpose of `<UserDefinedCommands>`; I just use it to add Notepad++ file bookmarks as well.

As you can observe from the syntax, you can add keyboard shortcuts to your bookmarks as well. This is more convenient to do from the Shortcut Mapper rather than editing the file, in order to avoid having to lookup key codes. But I usually don't bother with adding custom keyboard shortcuts; all the bookmarks are accessible using the regular access keys, without having to remember anything. E.g. for the bookmark above, I press `Alt + R` and then `M` to open shortcuts.xml. If you want to use a letter other than the first letter of the `Command name` you typed, you can specify that letter with `&`, e.g. `Command name="Modify &shortcuts.xml`, which will be underlined in the menu.

More info about adding items to Notepad++ Run menu is at [Notepad++ User Manual - Configuration Files Details](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#userdefinedcommands).